# Upgrade to 16.10 leaves broken packages

Tags: upgrade

after upgrading from Kubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 I am running into a bunch of issues.

I tried to fix them with: `sudo apt-get -f install` and several other attempts.

One of the problems seems to be with `kde-l10n-nl`

below the result of `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libboost-date-time1.58.0 libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-iostreams1.58.0 libicu55:i386
  libjson-c2:i386 libkf5activitiesexperimentalstats1 libkwinxrenderutils7 libmircommon5 liborcus-0.10-0v5
  libprocps4 libprotobuf9v5 libwacom-bin libxdelta2 linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-46 linux-headers-4.4.0-46-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-47 linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-4.4.0-46-generic linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic
  ubuntu-core-launcher xdelta
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-l10n-nl libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 libkf5kipi-bin libkf5screen7
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libkf5kipi30.0.0 libkf5screen6
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 libkf5kipi-bin libkf5screen7
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kde-l10n-nl
1 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 2 to remove and 829 not upgraded.
967 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 211 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [J/n] j
(Reading database ... 344785 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-l10n-nl_4%3a16.04.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking kde-l10n-nl (4:16.04.3-0ubuntu1) over (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-l10n-nl_4%3a16.04.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/HTML/nl/khelpcenter/index.cache.bz2', which is also in package khelpcenter 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-l10n-nl_4%3a16.04.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried: `sudo apt autoremove` which also tells me

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gwenview : Depends: libkf5kipi-bin (>= 16.04) but it is not installed
 kde-spectacle : Depends: libkf5kipi-bin (>= 16.04) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libkf5screen7 (>= 4:5.6.3) but it is not installed
 kscreen : Depends: libkf5screen7 (>= 4:5.6.3) but it is not installed
 libkf5i18n-data : Breaks: kde-l10n-nl (< 4:16.04.2) but 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
 libkf5screen-bin : Depends: libkf5screen7 (>= 4:5.7.1) but it is not installed
 libpowerdevilcore2 : Depends: libkf5screen7 (>= 4:5.6.3) but it is not installed
 plasma-desktop-data : Breaks: kde-l10n-nl (< 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu3~) but 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix are very welcome.

Comment: I would try deleting the problem file "/usr/share/doc/HTML/nl/khelpcenter/index.cache.bz2". The name suggests it's a cache file, so it shouldn't hurt anything if you remove it. You could also just rename it to be safe.

Comment: thank you for that. However I sort of solved this eventually by purging packages which where broken .. reinstalling them and many reconfigure attempts later it was sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up purging many packages from my installation to finally be able to do a error free `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and reinstalling many modules.

khelpcenter was just one of many I had to purge and reinstall.
I had to also ude `dpkg --configure -a` a few times in between.

To be honest I can't remember all the steps.
I am now left with a slight issue unresolved in this question: [Ubuntu boots to “Read Only Filesystem” after Upgrading from 16.04 > 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864171/ubuntu-boots-to-read-only-filesystem-after-upgrading-from-16-04-16-10)